# ¿Se puede utilizar la búsqueda hash en archivos RAF?

Tags: java, hash

¿Se puede utilizar la búsqueda hash en un archivo RandomAccessFile?

EDITADO:
Sé cómo implementar el Hashing cuando se trata de un vector (tengo las funciones Hash ya creadas y funcionan perfectamente), sin embargo me está costando implementarlo en un archivo de RAF pues no logro colocar los datos en la posición que deben ir.

Answer (score 0):

Sí se puede pero requieres implementarla.

Hay una clase java.io.RandomAccessFile que puedes usar.

Aquí está la liga de la clase:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Pero ocupas hacer la implementación del Hashing, la clase RAF solo te va a servir para hacer las búsquedas y operaciones de IO.